# Using NHibernate, how can I retrieve a list of composite-element objects given a parent's ID?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, hql, criteria, criteria-api

I presume this is an elementary question, but can't seem to find the answer. Using NHibernate, given a mapping with a one-to-many composite-element:

```
<class name="Event">
  <id name="Id">
    <generator class="guid" />
  </id>
  <set name="Items">
    <key column="EventId" />
    <composite-element class="EventItem">
        <property name="SomeProperty">
    </composite-element>
  </set>
 </class>
```

How can I return an IList of just the child Items given a parent ID? I'd love to see an example in both HQL and criteria. My feeble and unsuccessful attempt:

```
session.CreateQuery("FROM Event.Items WHERE Event.Id = :id")
   .SetParameter("id", eventId)
   .List<EventItem>();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several hours of looking, naturally I found the answer as soon as I posted.

```
session.CreateQuery("SELECT elements(e.Items) FROM Event e WHERE e.Id = :id")
   .SetParameter("id", eventId)
   .List<EventItem>();
```

Comment: Reading the docs wouldn't have hurt http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#queryhql-select

Comment: Yea I looked through the docs thoroughly but not end to end, so I missed it. Mostly I was confused about the right terminology to use